# A test of Survival

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

In the American TV series Survivor, there was once a game in which the participants were divided into two teams,say A and B. The team which removed the last flag was declared the winner.There were 25 flags with the teams allowed to remove 1,2 or 3 flags at each try with A starting first. Also, if one team has no chances of winning, it always chooses the maximum number of flags.

**If optimum play is assumed, which team wins? What if there were $n$ flags?**

Bonus question:
**What will happen if we increase the number of teams to 3? How will the winning chances of A and B be affected?**

Comment: I once played but with number of flags 12,24, ..., and play second. if the first chose x , I play 4-x (ex first chose 3, I choose 1)

Comment: similar to this one: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/30399/19989 (except for the bonus question).

Comment: One of the reasons why I put the bonus question...

Comment: @ffao I clarified that in an edit...

Comment: Indeed you did, I must be blind u.u

Comment: by "no chance" of winning, you mean that team X knows that the other teams play the optimal strategy or they can just hope in someone else's mistake?

Comment: @Marius Optimal play means no mistakes I think. For example at 5 flags, A won't win. He thus chooses 3 flags and not 1 or 2 flag.

Comment: This sounds like that Ishtori mini-game in Tales of Phantasia. is there any chance they're related ?

Comment: @IWonderHowLongANameICanTypeInH This game has been played since ancient times, making it much older than either Survivor or Tales of Phantasia. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim), its exact origin is unknown.

Comment: @Sid At 5 flags, isn't choosing 1 the winning strategy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The well-known answers to the first questions are:

> The second player can always make his move so that the sum of both players' moves is 4. Therefore, for $n = 4k$, the first team loses, for all other $n$, first team moves to a multiple of 4 and wins. In particular, for 25 flags and optimal play, team A starts by removing one flag and wins.

Since no one answered the modified bonus yet:

> First, note that who wins in any given position is determined by who wins in the positions with 1,2 or 3 less flags (since A will choose his move based on this). If A can move and leave a position in which the third player wins, they will do so, otherwise they will remove 3.
>
>  - For $1 \le n \le 3$, A wins.
>  - For $4 \le n \le 6$, A can't move to a C-winning position, so A removes 3 and B wins.
>  - For $n = 7$, C wins. A still can't win, and leaves 4 to B, who has to hand the win to C.
>  - For $8 \le n \le 10$, A moves to the C-position 7 and wins.
>
>  The winners for $1 \le n \le 3$ and $8 \le n \le 10$ are the same, so we have reached a cycle. In this case, A wins for $n \in \{7k + 1,7k+2,7k+3\}$, B wins for $n \in \{7k+4,7k+5,7k+6\}$ and C wins for $n=7k$.

Answer (score 4):

You can always easily arrange

> that your opponent's move, followed by yours that follows, removes a total of 4 flags.

Therefore,

> if the number of flags is *not* a multiple of 4 you can use your move to make it a multiple of 4, and from then on your opponent can never (and you will always) reduce the number to a multiple of 4. In particular, it must be you rather than your opponent who takes the number down to 0.

So

> with 25 flags, the first player (in this case A) will win; with *n* flags, the first player will win if *n* is not a multiple of 4 and the second player if *n* is a multiple of 4.

[EDITED to add: The following remarks about the 3-player version of the game were written before the OP changed the question to specify that a player who will definitely not win takes the maximum number of flags. Presumably we are to understand that this policy is common knowledge too. This of course invalidates what I wrote below.]

I think the main thing to say about the 3-player version is this:

> The player who wins may not be completely determined given only that each player maximizes their own winning opportunities, because there might be situations where A can't win but can choose whether B or C wins (e.g., this is the case if it's A's turn and there are exactly 5 flags remaining: if A removes 1 then C will win, else B will). So the result depends on each player's preferences *between the other players*.

Let's be more specific. I'll call the players 0,1,2 and suppose 0 has just played and 1 is about to. We can see, considering successively larger numbers of flags, that

> *with 0 flags*, 0 has just won
>  *with 1-3 flags*, 1 is about to win
>  *with 4 flags*, 2 will win
>  *with 5 flags*, player 1 chooses between 0,2 winning
>  *with 6 flags*, 1 will take one and then 2 chooses between 0,1 winning (the other options lead to situations where 1 will *definitely* not win)
>  *with 7 flags*, if 1 takes one then 0 chooses between 1,2 winning; if 1 takes two then 2 chooses between 0,1 winning; 1 will not take 3 because then 0 definitely wins

and so, in particular,

> the winner even for rather small *n* may depend on something as subtle as *whether player 1 thinks it more likely that 0 prefers 1 over 2, or that 2 prefers 1 over 0*.

As *n* increases

> the outcome will depend on increasingly multi-level considerations about whether A expects B to expect C to expect A to prefer B to C, etc. I'm pretty sure that for $n\geq7$ there are possible scenarios where any given player wins (even though in each such scenario, no player ever makes a choice that's unambiguously worse than another they could have made).

Comment: The question gives a way to resolve kingmakers: _if one team has no chances of winning, it always chooses the maximum number of flags_. See @ffao's answer.

Comment: @asgallant When I wrote the answer above, the question did not say that; it was added later, probably as a result of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's number the flags 1 to 25.
And your can start removing from 25 to 1.
Specific answer: $N=25$.

> Who removes flag 5 will remove flag 1 also no matter how many flags the other team removes. If team A removes flag 5, there are 4 left and the team B can leave 1, 2 or 3 flags. In each case team A can pick flag 1.
>  Who removes flag 9 will get to remove flat 5 also, hence flag 1 based on the same logic.
>  Going on this logic....
>  You have to remove flags, 5,9,13,17,21,25
>  So if team A starts, they should just remove 1 flag (#25) and follow the logic above and they will win for sure.

General for any $N$.

> Always remove any flag numbered $4\times K+1$.
>  If there are N flags, team A wins if $N \neq 4 \times K$ and loses otherwise.

Bonus question.

Let's say it's A's turn to pick.

> There are 4 flags left, A is a loser for sure so A picks 3 and B wins.
>  There are 5 flags left, A picks 1 and makes B the sure loser (case above). If they pick 2 or 3, B wins, so A is a loser for sure. So A has to pick 3.
>  There are 6 left, A picks 1 and make B the loser for sure (case above), So B has to pick 3 and C wins, this makes A a sure loser.  If A picks 2, same thing happens. B is sure loser, C wins.  If A picks 3, B wins, so in any case A is the sure loser so they have to pick 3 and B wins.
>  There are 7 left. A picks 1, B has to pick 3 (case above) and C wins.  Same goes for A picks 2. So A is again the sure loser So they have to pick 3. In this case C wins.
>  There are 8 left. A picks 1, B has to pick 3 (case above) and C has to pick 3 (from the 4 left) and A wins.
>  There are 9/10 left. A picks 2/3, B has to pick 3 (case above) and C has to pick 3 (from the 5 left) and A wins.
>  There are 11 left. A picks X and makes B the winner because of the 2 cases above.  So A is the loser for sure, so they have to pick 3 and B wins.
>  There are 12 left. A picks 1 and makes puts B in the case above so C wins.  For A picks 2 and 3 B wins (cases above). So A picks 3 and B wins.

Postulating:

> Still trying to find a formula.

Below is the original answer before I know what happens with the losing team.
Case 1: Alliances (yeah, that's why you watch Survivor )

> If alliances are formed and you are not in an alliance you are screwed for sure.
>  Let's say you are on team A and B & C form an alliance, A always loses.
>  in order to make sure A picks #1, A has to pick #4, but here are the possible cases:
>  If there are 6 left after your pick, B + C pick all of them (3+3).
>  If there are 7 left after your pick, B picks 1 + C picks 1 so there are 5 left and you don't get a chance to play next round because B + C can pick them up.
>  If there are 8 left after your pick, B+C pick 3 and you end up as above.
>  If there are 9 left after your pick, B+C pick 4 and you end up as above.
>  If there are 10 left after your pick, B+C pick 5 and you end up as above.
>  If there are 11 left after your pick, B+C pick 2 and you are left with 9. You can bring the total down to 6,7 or 8 and you are in one of the cases above. So you lose.

Case 2: No alliances (bhuuuu).
Assuming that a losing team will just pick at random when they are sure they will lose.

> Who ever picks #5 is sure of losing because the second one after you will pick #1 no matter what the first after you picks.
>  If there are 6 flags left, you (team A) pick 1 and you have a 33% chance of winning (if B picks 1 because B will choose at random 1 2 or 3 because they know they are going to lose).
>  If there are 7 flags left, you (team A) pick 1 and you have a 67% chance of winning (B will be in the case above and will choose 1 because a 33% chance is better than none, and C will be the loser for sure).
>  If there are 8 flags left, you (team A) pick 2 on the same logic as above.
>  If there are 9 left, you pick 3 on the same logic as above.
>  If there are 10 left just pick at random because you are going to lose. What ever you choose, B will be in one of the cases above for 9,8 or 7 and they will pick to leave it at 6, C will pick 1 to leave it at 5 not to be the sure loser and you will lose.

Conclusion:

> Based on the same logic, you don't want to be left to pick when there are $5 \times K$ flags left because you are the loser for sure.
>  Who picks when there are $5 \times K$ left has a 0% chance of winning.
>  Who picks after the person above has 67% chance of winning.
>  The third team gets the rest of 33%.
>  So if A goes first with 25 flags, they lose for sure, B wins in 67% of the cases and C in 33%.

I hope I didn't miss anything in the logic.

Comment: Losing team doesn't choose at random. I clarified that in an edit.

Comment: Damn it...I was so focused on my edit, I didn't check the question again. I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 vs 1

> no matter the n, the one who starts will always win by keeping the increase of 4 per round. The ultimate goal is that after your turn, the opponent is stuck at n-4 flags left.

For 3 players

> There is no sure way for anyone to win, even with optimal play. But the second player is sure to lose. 
>  If a player plays optimal and makes the last round start at n-5 flag, the second player is basically screwed, and nothing stops him from taking 2 or 3 flags which would make the third player win, or just 1 to make the first player win, either way the second player will lose so no move will be optimal for him.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a general answer, if there are $2$ teams playing optimally, $F$ flags and each team is allowed to remove $1$ to $N$ flags, the winner is:

> The first team if $N+1\nmid F$, and the second team if $N+1\mid F$.

This is because:

> In the first case, the first team can always remove some number of flags such that the remaining number of flags is divisible by $N+1$, and the second team cannot after such a move, and $0$ is divisible by $N+1$.
> The second case is the same, just with the teams switching roles.